# Counting Sentences/Words in Perl Using Regex

Tags: regex, perl, count, cpu-word

This regex thing is getting old. :(
Yet another question:
I need to count the number of words and number of sentences in a paragraph. The code I tried using was this:

```
my $sentencecount = $file =~ s/((^|\s)\S).*?(\.|\?|\!)/$1/g;
my $count = $file =~ s/((^|\s)\S)/$2/g;
print "Input file $ARGV[1] contains $sentencecount sentences and $count words.";
```

My results return 63 for both counts. I know this is incorrect, as least as far as word count goes. Is this a result of using a substitution for the counting process? If so, how do I correct this?

Comment: You know, I think there may be easier ways to count words in a string...

Comment: Obviously you should post the input file.

Comment: Also `s///g` starts each match from *after* the replacement text (so that e.g. `s/a/ab/g` won't cause an infinite loop).  That's part of the problem here.  Also your sentence-counting regex is quite bizarre -- it replaces the first sentence with the first character from that sentence (possibly preceded by a single space) -- that's what's in `$1`.

Comment: But what about `C.S. Lewis` or `abr.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking into the perl `split` function, see `perlfunc(1)`:

```
           If EXPR is omitted, splits the $_ string.  If PATTERN is also
           omitted, splits on whitespace (after skipping any leading
           whitespace).  Anything matching PATTERN is taken to be a
           delimiter separating the fields.  (Note that the delimiter may
           be longer than one character.)
```

Comment: I was looking into the split function, actually, but the website I was on was honestly quite terrible and I didn't realize it at the time, so I skipped it, but yeah, thanks to you, I got this stupid code working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
my $wordCount = 0;
++$wordCount while $file =~ /\S+/g;

my $sentenceCount = 0;
++$sentenceCount while $file =~ /[.!?]+/g;
```

Doing `//g` matching in scalar context as we are here avoids building an enormous list of all words or all sentences, saving on memory if the file is large.  The sentence counting code will count any number of end-of-sentence delimiters as a single sentence (e.g. `Hello... world!` will be counted as 2 sentences.)

Answer (score 0):

This gets the count of sentences and chars from `$file`

```
$file="This is praveen worki67ng in RL websolutions";
my $count = () = $file =~ /\S+/g;
my $counter = () = $file =~ /\S/g;
```

Comment: this is get the count of sentences and chars from $file